# Работает curl с той же машины но не работает в соседней

Tags: apache, сеть, centos8, локальная-сеть

Установил на centos8 apache, php, mysql вроде работает все захожу через curl заглушка работает,

```
[root@web1-dev html]# curl http://localhost:12221/index.html
hello world
```

то же самое по ip

```
[root@web1-dev html]# curl http://192.168.2.4:12221/index.html
hello world
```

Но с соседнего компа уже ничего не работает

```
$ curl https://192.168.2.4:12221/index.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.4 port 12221: Timed out


$ ping 192.168.2.4

Pinging 192.168.2.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.4: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.4: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.4: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.4: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 7ms, Average = 4ms
```

Фаервол порты прописывал но ничего не работает из вне, куда копать?

Проблема решена: отключением фаервола (спасибо S.H.)

```
[antik@web1-dev ~]$ systemctl stop firewalld
....
[antik@web1-dev ~]$ systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2021-09-10 12:00:26 +05; 11s ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
  Process: 698 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid $FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 698 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: пинг идёт с соседнего компа на сервер?

Comment: Да идет дополнил вопрос результатом ping

Comment: А если совсем вырубить файервол - ситуация не меняется?

Comment: Попробуйте подключиться по telnet: `telnet 192.168.2.4 12221`

Comment: Есть вероятность, что у apache в конфиге не разрешено подключение со внешний IP

Comment: поменялась заработало, спасибо большое